# mutation observer doesn't work with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, mutation-observers

I tried to select each feed item of `facebook.com` which has the class of `userContentWrapper` but I got the 0 as length. Anything wrong with my observer below?

```
   var insertedNodes = [];
   var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, observer) {

       mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {

        $(mutation).closest('.userContentWrapper').css({'background':'red'});

        console.log($(mutation).closest('.userContentWrapper')) // length 0

        })
   });

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe($('[id^=topnews_main_stream_]').get(0), {childList: true, subtree:true});
```

Comment: the `mutations` argument isn't a list of elements, so jQuery has no idea what to do with `$(mutation)`

Comment: @JaromandaX mutations has a callback, it passed mutation

Comment: mutations is an array of mutations ... it doesn't have *a callback* (whatever the heck that means)

Comment: to clarify, "mutations" is an array of [mutation records](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord) - using a "mutation record" as a "selector" for jQuery will not yield a result, as jQuery is too stupid to know what to do with a mutation record

Comment: @JaromandaX so it's not possible to do traversing? So what should I do?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean by "traversing" - read what a mutation record is - I gave you a link to what it is, read it - then you'll know what to put in your jQuery selector, and when to use it (i.e. on what TYPE of mutation record)

Comment: so I should do `$(MutationRecord.target)` ? I just want to apply random color on facebook's news feed item, that's about it.

Comment: well, in your code it'd be `$(mutation.target)` ... and it would not necessarily be for every mutation record, depends if any nodes were added or not (removing nodes is a mutation too)